# adding 2 arraylists to another arraylist

Tags: java

I have 2 arraylist like this, but im not sure how i can combine them together. I have tried the Collections.copy() and addAll method but it wouldnt work, I want to know if there is any way I can combine them together into another arraylist? What I really want is to have the first arraylist storing the data from the second arraylist, so each of the Point would have a few lines inside it. Maybe you guys can give me some suggestions of how i can do this please, thanks.

```
 static ArrayList<Vertex> getPoints() {
      Scanner input = Reader(Vertex.airports);
      ArrayList<Vertex> result = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

      while(input.hasNext()){
          String point = input.nextLine();
          result.add(new Vertex(point));

      }
      input.close();
      return result;

  }

  static ArrayList<Edge> getlines(){
          Scanner input = Reader(Vertex.graph);
          ArrayList<Edge> result = new ArrayList<Edge>();

          while(input.hasNext()){
              String route = input.nextLine();
              result.add(new Edge(route));
          }
          input.close();
          return result;

      }
```

the data are from 2 text files, the file looks like this. They are just some of it to show what Im trying to do here.
(index,name)

```
1 England
2 France
```

### 3 Holland

(index,start,cost,end)

```
1 1 2 2
2 1 3 1
3 1 6 3
4 1 7 3
5 2 1 2
6 2 3 1
7 2 4 1
8 2 5 2
9 2 6 2
10 3 1 1
11 3 2 1
12 3 4 1
13 3 8 1
14 3 10 2
```

thanks to Captain Ford this is completed!

Comment: This isn't clear.  What kind of result are you expecting?

Comment: `addAll` definitely *does* work. When you say that something doesn't work, it's useful to say what result you were expecting and what you actually saw.

Comment: Are you trying to combine an `ArrayList<Edge>` and an `ArrayList<Vertex>`?

Comment: um im expecting my program in the future can use the data say i wanna travel from england to Germany, and my program will be able to use the data, and out print the 2...so what im looking for now is to combine the 2 together so i can access to the data by using one arraylist in the program rather then calling both of them and connecting them again

Comment: Yes im trying to combine an ArrayList<Edge> and an ArrayList<Vertex>, but what i really want is the airports will have the edges stored inside it so when i call the airport, it give me all the possible edges the vertex has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can improve on my other answer.

A more complete solution would look like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Airport {
    public final int id;
    public String name;
    public List<Route> outboundRoutes = new ArrayList<Route>();
    public List<Route> inboundRoutes = new ArrayList<Route>();

    public double minDistance;
    public Airport previous;

    public Airport(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static class Route {
        public final int id;
        public double cost;
        public Airport departure;
        public Airport destination;

        public Route(int id, double cost, Airport departure, Airport destination){
            this.id = id;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.departure = departure;
            this.destination = destination;
        }
    }


    public static Map<Integer,Airport> readAirports(Scanner input){
        Map<Integer,Airport> airports = new HashMap<Integer,Airport>();
        while(input.hasNext()){
            //  Using a map rather than a list simplifies the process of loading 
            //  your routes, and eliminates problems that would crop up if some
            //  airports are listed out of order or removed.
            Airport port = new Airport(input.nextInt(), input.next());
            airports.put(port.id, port);
        }
        return airports;
    }


    //  Note that the list of airports must be passed when loading the routes, 
    //  but that nothing is returned -- the routes are loaded directly 
    //  into the airports.
    public static void readRoutes(Scanner input, Map<Integer,Airport> airports){

        while(input.hasNext()){
            int id = input.nextInt();
            int departureId = input.nextInt();
            int destinationId = input.nextInt();
            double cost = input.nextDouble();

            if(!(airports.containsKey(departureId) && 
                    airports.containsKey(destinationId))){
                //  You'll have to decide how to handle a situation when a route 
                //  refers to airports that don't exist
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Undefined airport referenced in route #" + id);
            }

            Route route = new Route(id, cost, airports.get(departureId), 
                    airports.get(destinationId));
            route.departure.outboundRoutes.add(route);
            route.destination.inboundRoutes.add(route);
        }
    }

    public static Map<Integer,Airport> loadAirports() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner inAirports = new Scanner(new File("airports.txt"));
        Scanner inRoutes = new Scanner(new File("routes.txt"));
        Map<Integer,Airport> airports = readAirports(inAirports);
        readRoutes(inRoutes, airports);
        return airports;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Map<Integer,Airport> airports = loadAirports();
            for(Airport port : airports.values()){
                System.out.println(port.name + " has " + port.inboundRoutes.size() + " inbound routes and " + port.outboundRoutes.size() + " outbound routes ");
                for(Route r : port.inboundRoutes){
                    System.out.println("\tin from " + r.departure.name + " at a cost of $" + r.cost);
                }
                for(Route r : port.outboundRoutes){
                    System.out.println("\tout to " + r.destination.name + " at a cost of $" + r.cost);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted a simple, straight up answer, what you were wanting to do with ArrayLists can't be done without doing some kind of nesting.

Since you're working with data that has IDs, I would strongly recommend you use a HashMap anyway so you don't have to worry about your data not being in a perfect sequence. And since you have metadata (airport names), creating these classes is a good way to model the data.

Edit: Code has now been altered to all fit in one file. With the sample files you provided called "airports.txt" and "routes.txt" respectively, it should work just fine. When you run it, you should get the following output:

```
England(LHR) has 4 inbound routes and 4 outbound routes 
    in from France(CDG) at a cost of $2.0
    in from Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Portugal(LIS) at a cost of $3.0
    in from Iceland(KEF) at a cost of $3.0
    out to France(CDG) at a cost of $2.0
    out to Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Portugal(LIS) at a cost of $3.0
    out to Iceland(KEF) at a cost of $3.0
France(CDG) has 5 inbound routes and 5 outbound routes 
    in from England(LHR) at a cost of $2.0
    in from Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Germany(FRA) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Italy(LIN) at a cost of $2.0
    in from Portugal(LIS) at a cost of $2.0
    out to England(LHR) at a cost of $2.0
    out to Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Germany(FRA) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Italy(LIN) at a cost of $2.0
    out to Portugal(LIS) at a cost of $2.0
Holland(AMS) has 5 inbound routes and 5 outbound routes 
    in from England(LHR) at a cost of $1.0
    in from France(CDG) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Germany(FRA) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Denmark(CPH) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Finland(HEL) at a cost of $2.0
    out to England(LHR) at a cost of $1.0
    out to France(CDG) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Germany(FRA) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Denmark(CPH) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Finland(HEL) at a cost of $2.0
Germany(FRA) has 4 inbound routes and 4 outbound routes 
    in from France(CDG) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Italy(LIN) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Sweden(ARN) at a cost of $2.0
    out to France(CDG) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Italy(LIN) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Sweden(ARN) at a cost of $2.0
Italy(LIN) has 3 inbound routes and 3 outbound routes 
    in from France(CDG) at a cost of $2.0
    in from Germany(FRA) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Portugal(LIS) at a cost of $3.0
    out to Portugal(LIS) at a cost of $3.0
    out to France(CDG) at a cost of $2.0
    out to Germany(FRA) at a cost of $1.0
Portugal(LIS) has 3 inbound routes and 3 outbound routes 
    in from England(LHR) at a cost of $3.0
    in from France(CDG) at a cost of $2.0
    in from Italy(LIN) at a cost of $3.0
    out to England(LHR) at a cost of $3.0
    out to France(CDG) at a cost of $2.0
    out to Italy(LIN) at a cost of $3.0
Iceland(KEF) has 1 inbound routes and 1 outbound routes 
    in from England(LHR) at a cost of $3.0
    out to England(LHR) at a cost of $3.0
Denmark(CPH) has 2 inbound routes and 2 outbound routes 
    in from Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Norway(OSL) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Holland(AMS) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Norway(OSL) at a cost of $1.0
Norway(OSL) has 2 inbound routes and 2 outbound routes 
    in from Denmark(CPH) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Sweden(ARN) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Denmark(CPH) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Sweden(ARN) at a cost of $1.0
Finland(HEL) has 2 inbound routes and 2 outbound routes 
    in from Holland(AMS) at a cost of $2.0
    in from Sweden(ARN) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Sweden(ARN) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Holland(AMS) at a cost of $2.0
Sweden(ARN) has 3 inbound routes and 3 outbound routes 
    in from Germany(FRA) at a cost of $2.0
    in from Norway(OSL) at a cost of $1.0
    in from Finland(HEL) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Germany(FRA) at a cost of $2.0
    out to Norway(OSL) at a cost of $1.0
    out to Finland(HEL) at a cost of $1.0
```

Comment: may i ask what does the airport class has float x,y? are they the start point and end point(departure and destination)?

Comment: i understand now why i cant use an arraylist now and using a hashmap is properly a much better idea...but theres a few things i dont understand. 1. do i keep my code for reading the data into the arraylist? Cos now im not sure where to put in the text file.

Comment: can you tell me how can i get it to come out with some kind of output please, because Im not too sure how you a getting the data from the text file now and i would like to print something out with it to test it and give me a better understanding in this. thanks

Comment: Sorry, got distracted. The x,y coordinates replace the Vertex you were using before. You can use whatever you like, but I just put something in there to represent it. I simplified the input a bit by making it so you pass the Scanner in as a parameter, so you deal with all the file I/O elsewhere and only call these methods to do the parsing. It doesn't exactly match your file format. But then, your file format doesn't contain information for a vertex, either.

Comment: well i actually have a class call vertex, it contains the id and name, another class call edge which contains the id,start,end and cost. but im guess i will not need them if im using the code u provided, right??

Comment: I had a feeling that was what you were doing. I basically just gave your classes different names and used direct references to airports instead of numeric ids in the routes.

Comment: okok i will try to use the classes you provided for now, anyway i have now put the file into these methods, the airports text file for the loadAirports and graph text file for the loadRoutes, correct me if im wrong please.... ;) but can you show me how i can use these data to test and see if it works please?? and to test if it is reading the correct value.

Comment: I added a mainline to the bottom. Hmm...I suppose I could put it all into one java file so you could just copy and paste it.

Comment: it gives me an error when i was trying to run it,  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at dijkstra.connecting.loadRoutes(connecting.java:43)
 at dijkstra.connecting.main(connecting.java:53)
Line 43 is the   route.departure.outboundRoutes.add(route);
and line 53 is the    loadRoutes(inRoutes, airports);

Comment: This new version should work right out of the box if you have the files in the right place.

Comment: hi there, I have just updated my text files at the top, they are all the data from my actual file. Can you see if you can run all of them becuase i tried just now and it wouldnt give me any values for anything after holland. but actually they have inbound and outbound as well..now is all like ---> 
Germany(FRA) has 0 inbound routes and 4 outbound routes 
Italy(LIN) has 0 inbound routes and 3 outbound routes

Comment: Okay, I see that now. I made an error in the output -- it's looping over the inbound list twice when it should be doing the inbound and then the outbound.

Comment: Ah, I see what's wrong. In your original definition of the routes file you had the cost between the start and end. That's why it's doing that. I'll fix it in a minute.

Comment: Wow...thank you soooooo much!!!!!! now this is actually working and its reading everything correctly...thank you so much!!! i have been stuck on this for at least 2 weeks now!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my understanding is that the first list contains a list of airports, and the second list connects the airports in the first list.

If you want to store references to the lines with the associated points, you would need to create a wrapper around the points that contains another list.

```
class Airport {
    public Vertex point;
    public List<Edge> routes = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    public Airport(Vertex p){
        this.point = p;
    }
}
```

Then when you're loading your lists, you would do something like this:

```
static ArrayList<Airport> getAirports() {
    Scanner input = Reader(Vertex.airports);
    ArrayList<Vertex> result = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

    while(input.hasNext()){
        String point = input.nextLine();
        //  Note the small change on the next line
        result.add(new Airport(new Vertex(point)));

    }
    input.close();
    return result;
}

static ArrayList<Edge> getlines(){
    Scanner input = Reader(Vertex.graph);
    ArrayList<Edge> result = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    while(input.hasNext()){
        String route = input.nextLine();
        result.add(new Edge(route));
    }
    input.close();
    return result;

}

static void combineLists(List<Airport> airports, List<Edge> lines){
    for(Edge edge : lines){
        //  This is where we add the routes to both airports
        //  Since I don't know the structure of the edge class, I'm making a guess that you're using the integer indices that were described in the file to describe the endpoints. Note, however, that you will need to find a way to guarantee that they match the indices of the list of airports.
        airports.get(edge.p1).routes.add(edge);
        airports.get(edge.p2).routes.add(edge);
    }
}
```